# How to make gsub() work on entire column?

Tags: r, gsub, hebrew

I am trying to make gsub replace hex characters I have into Hebrew abc,
Using the following function:

```
name<-gsub("\u0080","א",name)
name<-gsub("\u0081","ב",name)
name<-gsub("\u0082","ג",name)
name<-gsub("\u0083","ד",name)
name<-gsub("\u0084","ה",name)
name<-gsub("\u0085","ו",name)
name<-gsub("\u0086","ז",name)
name<-gsub("\u0087","ח",name)
name<-gsub("\u0088","ח",name)   
name<-gsub("\u0089","י",name)
name<-gsub("\u008a","ך",name)
name<-gsub("\u008b","כ",name)
name<-gsub("\u008c","ל",name)
name<-gsub("\u008d","ם",name)
name<-gsub("\u008e","מ",name)
name<-gsub("\u008f","ן",name)
name<-gsub("\u0090","נ",name)
name<-gsub("\u0091","ס",name)
name<-gsub("\u0092","ע",name)
name<-gsub("\u0093","ף",name)
name<-gsub("\u0094","פ",name)
name<-gsub("\u0095","ץ",name)
name<-gsub("\u0096","צ",name)
name<-gsub("\u0097","ק",name)
name<-gsub("\u0098","ר",name)
name<-gsub("\u0099","ש",name)
name<-gsub("\u009a","ת",name)
```

I have a variable called 'name' which contains the hex characters (for example):

```
[1] "-"                                                                          
[2] "\u0083 \u0087\u0082\u0080 \u008f\u008c\u0098\u0080 \u0081\u0089\u0081\u0080"
[3] "-"                                                                          
[4] "\u0084 \u0087\u0082\u0080 \u008f\u008c\u0098\u0080 \u0081\u0089\u0081\u0080"
```

When inserting the values into vector, manually, like this:

```
name<- c("-" ,                                                       
"\u0083 \u0087\u0082\u0080 \u008f\u008c\u0098\u0080 \u0081\u0089\u0081\u0080",
 "-"    ,                                                                      
"\u0084 \u0087\u0082\u0080 \u008f\u008c\u0098\u0080 \u0081\u0089\u0081\u0080")
```

and running my script it works, but, when I try to make it run through the whole database, by using the following script to insert the values into 'name' variable:

```
cond<-list_kind %in% c("02")
name<-ifelse(cond,substr(data_set$data_from_row,25,39),"-")
```

(Because I need only the names in list kind 2)

it just prints the name as it was, as hex.

Comment: You can replace the numerous `gsub` calls with a single `chartr` call.

Comment: Thanks G.Grothendieck.
I used
    chartr
instead and it worked